# Saving Related Data in CakePHP 3 Controller

Tags: orm, entity, cakephp-3.0

In the documentation exactly says that associated data can be saved like:

```
use App\Model\Entity\Article;
use App\Model\Entity\User;

$article = new Article(['title' => 'First post']);
$article->user = new User(['id' => 1, 'username' => 'mark']);

$articles = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
$articles->save($article);
```

I tried this in my code but I get error:

Fatal Error
Error: Class 'App\Controller\TableRegistry' not found
File /Users/mtkocak/Sites/gscrm/src/Controller/BusinessesController.php 
Line: 62

Here is my controller code. I am doubt that above code is valid for entity models.

```
    public function add() {
    $business = $this->Businesses->newEntity($this->request->data);
    $record = new Record($this->request->data['Records']);

    $address = new Address($this->request->data['Addresses']);
    $telephone = new Telephone($this->request->data['Telephones']);
    $email = new Email($this->request->data['Emails']);

    $record->business = $business;
    $record->address = $address;
    $record->email = $email;

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        var_dump($this->request->data['Records']);
        $records = TableRegistry::get('Records');
        $records->save($record);
        // if ($this->Businesses->save($business)) {
        //     $this->Flash->success('The business has been saved.');
        //     return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        // } else {
        //     $this->Flash->error('The business could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        // }
    }
    $telephonetypes = $this->Businesses->Records->Telephones->Telephonetypes->find('list');
    $records = $this->Businesses->Records->find('list');
    $businesstypes = $this->Businesses->Businesstypes->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('telephonetypes','business', 'records', 'businesstypes'));
}
```

Here is my sql dump of table:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `businesses` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `record_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `businesstype_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_turkish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

ALTER TABLE `businesses`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`), ADD KEY `FK_businesses_records` (`record_id`), ADD KEY `FK_businesses_businesstypes` (`businesstype_id`);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You are missing a `use` statement. All these examples in the book take for granted that you've started reading the tables section from the beginning and make use of:

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#getting-instances-of-a-table-class**

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
```

ps. you don't have to build the entities manually when following the naming conventions

- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#converting-request-data-into-entities**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#avoiding-property-mass-assignment-attacks**

Comment: I have the "use" statement and am still getting the error.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157865/why-am-i-getting-tableregistry-not-found-in-cakephp-3-0).