# Why am I getting "TableRegistry not found" in CakePhP 3.0?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

I have a class full of static functions that I call UtilityFunctions in my Model/ directory.  But that class cannot access TableRegistry::Get even though the "use" statements are in place.  Below is the code and the error.

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use App\Model\Entity\Device;

class UtilityFunctions {
    public static function getDevice($deviceInfo) {
        $devicesTable = TableRegistry::get('Devices'); // TableRegistry not found
        $query = $devicesTable->findByDeviceInfo($deviceInfo);
       ...
    }
}
```

"Class \u0027UtilityFunctions\TableRegistry\u0027 not found",
"/var/www/myserver/src/Model/Custom/UtilityFunctions.php",115

Comment: I think its because it is called in a static function, try adding a backslash at the beginning - `\TableRegistry::get('Devices')`

Comment: How are you calling that method?

Answer (score 9):

I know that this might be a really late reply, but it may be an issue with you not inserting `use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;` at the top of the code.

I had the same issue. I added that line of code and it worked

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the order of the lines. If you place `namespace` first, PHP will look inside the given namespace unless you specify a \ first in the `use` statement . E.g.

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
```

will look for App\Model\Table\Cake\ORM\TableRegistry, which obviously isn't right.

But this will work:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
namespace App\Model\Table;
```

Or

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
use \Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
```